# Prolog: counting atoms in a list

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to count atoms in a list.  I can count all the atoms but I can't count a specific atom.  I know there's something wrong with my code but I'm not sure how to fix it.

This works to count all the atoms in a list (the E (element) is irrelevant here):

```
count_atoms(_,[],0).
count_atoms(E,[H|T],R):- number(H), count_atoms(E,T,R1),R is R1,!.
count_atoms(E,[H|T],R):- var(H), count_atoms(E,T,R1),R is R1,!.
count_atoms(E,[H|T],R):- atom(H), count_atoms(E,T,R1),R is R1+1,!.
```

But this doesn't work to find the E (element) in the list:

```
count_atoms(_,[],0).
count_atoms(E,[H|T],R):- number(H), count_atoms(E,T,R1),R is R1,!.
count_atoms(E,[H|T],R):- var(H), count_atoms(E,T,R1),R is R1,!.
count_atoms(E,[H|T],R):- atom(H), E==H, count_atoms(E,T,R1),R is R1+1,!.
```

The result I get each time is just `false.`
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't plan to write an answer, but I would see if SWI-Prolog's [aggregate_all](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate) with `count` would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not state what happens if `H` is an atom but not equal to `E`.

Add this:

```
count_atoms(E,[H|T],R):- atom(H), E\==H, count_atoms(E,T,R),!.
```

Output:

```
?- count_atoms(a,[a,b,a,c],R).
R = 2.
```

Also there is a lot of improvement possible.

Comment: Thank you!  Much appreciated.

Comment: @theWhiteKnight ^^ you can accept an answer by clicking the grey checkmark left to the answer. Also if you like an answer you can upvote it by clicking the upwards triangle.

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered by @DuDa - ypu forgot to take care of the case of a list member that is an atom different from whatever E is bound to. In addition, you didn't take care of the case that H is a structure.

I would only like to add that it makes things easier, if you do not try to enumerate all cases, but work with a catch-all clause, for expl:

```
count_atoms(_,[],0).
count_atoms(E,[E|T],R):- atom(E),count_atoms(E,T,R1),R is R1+1,!.
count_atoms(E,[_|T],R):- count_atoms(E,T,R). % catch-all
```

Even with the addition of the answer above, the proof of a question will still fail with lists that contain structures like `[a,b,c,f(d),e]`, whereas it works with a catch-all clause.

For example, Prolog will answer the question `?- count_atoms(a,[a,b,c,f(d),e],R).` with *no* even with the addition above, but with `R = 1.` when using a catch-all clause.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach:

```
count(H,List,Count):-   
    count1(H,List,0,Count).

count1(_, [], Count, Count). %base case
count1(H,[K|T],CountA,Count):-  %Count atom in List
    H=K,
    CountB is CountA+1,
    count1(H,T,CountB,Count).
count1(H,[K|T],CountA,Count):- %Don't count when atom not in list
    H\=K,
    count1(H,T,CountA,Count).
```

**Example:**

```
?- count(a,[a,a,a],Count).
Count = 3
false

?- count(b,[a,a,b,n,n,a],Count).
Count = 1
false

?- count(n,[a,a,b,n,n,a],Count).
Count = 2
false

?- count(c,[a,a,b,n,n,a],Count).
Count = 0
false
```

Answer (score 0):

In SWI-Prolog, another possible solution is:

```
count_atoms(Atom, List, Count) :-
     aggregate_all(count,
                   (member(Item, List),
                    atom(Item),
                    Item = Atom),
                   Count).
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- count_atoms(a, [a,b,a,X,c,f(d),a,Y,b,a], Count).
Count = 4.

?- count_atoms(b, [a,b,a,X,c,f(d),a,Y,b,a], Count).
Count = 2.

?- count_atoms(c, [a,b,a,X,c,f(d),a,Y,b,a], Count).
Count = 1.

?- count_atoms(d, [a,b,a,X,c,f(d),a,Y,b,a], Count).
Count = 0.
```